# simple permanent redirect 301 dynamic url to static url page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

what is best rule for 301 redirect

http://iwanet.org/iwa-membership/51?start=4

to this page

http://iwanet.org/about/web-professional-standards/

Comment: Will it be a permanent redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=4$
RewriteRule ^iwa-membership/51$ /about/web-professional-standards/ [L,R=301]
```